# Does pythonanywhere allow install other Git version in a free account?

Tags: git, pythonanywhere

I'm trying to run this command in bash console of pythonanywhere;

[image: error]

Text version:

```
git config credential.helper 'cache --timeout=900'
fatal: not in a git repository
```

Comment: `git` works and reports an error about the current directory not being a repository. Change directory to your repository and continue.

Comment: Sorry for the image that I uploaded. I forgot to put it on text version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF you want to execute it from anywhere, configure the setting globally:

```
git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=900'
```

That way, you don't depend on the current folder.
But that would apply to *all* your repositories.

Comment: I did with the **--gobal** option and solved my problem. I'm going to use this form for a while with my free web hosting in **pythonanywhere**.